# Creating an action filter attribute that bypasses the actual execution of the action and returns a value for it

Tags: asp.net, attributes, actionfilterattribute

Can I create an ActionFilterAttribute that bypasses the actual execution of the action and returns a value for it?

Comment: Do you mean if its unauthorized?

Comment: @Fals Not necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, like this:

1) Redirects to some action and then return some value:

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        /*If something happens*/
        if (/*Condition*/)
        {
            /*You can use Redirect or RedirectToRoute*/
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("Redirecto to somewhere");
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
 }
```

2) Write some value direcly into the request and Ends it sending to the client:

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        /*If something happens*/
        if (/*Condition*/)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("some value here");
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible. You can set the result of the filter context provided to you when overriding `OnActionExecuting` in `ActionFilterAttribute`.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public sealed class SampleFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext )
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult( "http://google.com" );
    }
}
```

In the source, you can see that setting the `Result` property of the filter context changes the flow.

From System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker:

```
internal static ActionExecutedContext InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func<ActionExecutedContext> continuation)
{
    filter.OnActionExecuting(preContext);
    if (preContext.Result != null)
    {
        return new ActionExecutedContext(preContext, preContext.ActionDescriptor, true /* canceled */, null /* exception */)
        {
            Result = preContext.Result
        };
    }

    // other code ommitted
}
```